# Linked list / Graph C

Tags: c, graph, linked-list

I'm looking for a way to connect elements like a graph but with linked lists.
As far as I know this is how work a simple linked list[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffzvl.png)

But only one element is connected to another one. I know there is the double linked list but there is 2 connections.

How is it possible to connect element to others ?

I saw the concept of graph but I don't have a clue on how to do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrGun.png)
Here's an example of graph I would like to realise.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is a simple single-linked list, one of the simplest and most basic data-structures in any language. There are *tons* of tutorials about them all over.

Comment: How good is your understanding of pointers? I am asking that because we can suggest resources based on how much you already know.

Comment: My understanding of pointers is basic, I mean I know the basics and how a pointer works, I'll be glad if you know some good ressources about graph. Thanks

Comment: You can read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_algorithms.htm It tries to explain linked list in a general way, not specific to C. Once you understand the concept you can see (or try to figure out) how to implement in C.

Comment: Thank you for this link, however I understand the linked lists, I just want to know how to set up a graph using or not linked lists

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/ I found this link, it seems to explain well the graph, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need what is called an `adjacency list`.

It may consist in a linked list of `int*` in which each element represents an array of adjacencies(i.e other vertices that are linked to this one) of a vertex in the graph. It should be something like this:

```
list *adj // Of course it depends on how you implemented the list
```

For this, i'm assuming that each vertex has its own index.

Comment: I think adjacency list is not what he wants. He wants the nodes of the graph to be actual linked list nodes - Pointers joining graph nodes to each other. But since the answer is accepted, I believe he is satisfied.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, I found a website than explains how to create a graph in c and it seems to explain your method with more informations,